# ASP.NET MVC (FX) Date values not showing up inside HTML.EditorFor from database model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date

In my ASP.Net MVC (FX) application I am saving 2 date values in this manor:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "Hire Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

...

<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Date, "Injury Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injury_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>
```

The model looks like this for that field:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime Hire_Date { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime Injury_Date { get; set; }
```

And this saves to the database correctly. This data can also be retrieved and displayed on later screens, such as the Details.cshtml screen like this:

```
<dt>
            Hire Date
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Hire_Date)
        </dd>

        ......

        <dt>
            Injury Date
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Injury_Date)
        </dd>
```

[image: details]

Which is simple enough and makes sense, but on the Edit.cshtml page and a few others in which these date fields need to be editable, I can't figure out how I can display what the date value currently is to the user as well as give them the means to change it.

This is what I currently have in Edit.cshtml:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "Hire Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
            </div>
```

But as you can see this does not show the user what those date's currently are:

[image: edit]

Although they can change that value.

How can I both display the existing date(s) to the user while also allowing them to edit it?

EDIT 1:

I have updated the Edit.cshtml view to look like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "Hire Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = @Model.Hire_Date.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy"), @class = "datepicker" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
            </div>
```

On both dates adding the `@Value = @Model.Hire_Date.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy"),` but this has not changed anything.

EDIT 2: I am including my Edit controller:

```
// GET: WC_Inbox/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            WC_Inbox wC_Inbox = db.WC_Inbox.Find(id);
            if (wC_Inbox == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(wC_Inbox.EmployeeID);
            string fullName = employee.First_Name + " " + employee.Last_Name;
            string addUser = wC_Inbox.Add_User;
            ViewBag.EmployeeID = id;
            ViewBag.Name = fullName;
            ViewBag.Add_User = addUser;

            return View(wC_Inbox);
        }

// POST: WC_Inbox/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,InboxID,EmployeeID,District,Org_Number,Hire_Date,Job_Title,Work_Schedule,Injury_Date,Injury_Time,DOT_12,Start_Time,Injured_Body_Part,Side,Missing_Work,Return_to_Work_Date,Doctors_Release,Treatment,Injury_Description,Equipment,Witness,Questioned,Medical_History,Inbox_Submitted,Inbox_Reason,Comments,User_Email,Contact_Email,Specialist_Email,Optional_Email,Optional_Email2,Optional_Email3,Optional_Email4, Add_User")] WC_Inbox wC_Inbox)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                
                db.Entry(wC_Inbox).State = EntityState.Modified;
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var errors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in errors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            // get the error message 
                            string errorMessage = validationError.ErrorMessage;
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorMessage);

                        }
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "First_Name", wC_Inbox.EmployeeID);
            return View(wC_Inbox);
        }
```

EDIT 3:

This is how those date values are originally entered in the Create.cshtml page:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "Hire Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? If it's rendering an `<input type="date" ...`, then the value needs to use the `yyyy-MM-dd` format. [<input type="date"> | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: The pictures I shared in the question show what the rendered html looks like. Why would you suggest that it needs to use the ````yyyy-MM-dd```` format when it accepts ````mm-dd-yyyy```` and displays it in this format on the Details page as shown in the image?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the HTML in the "view source", not the actual UI of the page. If it's rendering an `<input type="date">`, then the value has to be in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format, even though the browser will display it using the user's regional settings.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Check out EDIT 3 on my question. I added the Create page where I insert one of those date values. Is this the situation you are describing? I believe so. If it is, what do I need to change?

Comment: You can either right-click on your page and select "view page source", or right-click on the date picker element and select "inspect element". Either way, you should be able to see the HTML which was sent to your browser. You're just looking to see if it was sent as an `<input type="date">` or an `<input type="text">`.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure we are understanding each other here. I'm not quite sure how you think that would help the end user. I'm not trying to be rude, but maybe you should go back and read my question.

Comment: I have read your question. Your controller generates HTML which is rendered by the browser. Your question states that the date values are not shown in the date inputs. I am simply trying to get you to verify what HTML is being sent to the browser, so that you can determine the correct format for the `value` attribute.

Comment: I understand now. If I inspect the Edit view the value of Hire Date is ````value="9/2/2021"```` which is correct. Now, it is not in the format that you said was required, but what if I want it to be in the format that it is now?

Comment: Does it have `type="date"` or `type="text"`? If it's `type="date"`, then it needs to be `value="2021-09-02"` for the browser to recognise the value as a valid date. The browser will take care of displaying the date in the format which the end-user expects.

Comment: ````type="date"````

Comment: Ok so how can I change the format? The dates are saved in the database as mm-dd-yyyy. How can I change them before giving the values to the page?

Comment: Your properties are `DateTime` values, so hopefully your database values are stored as `date` columns rather than `varchar` columns. Date columns don't have an associated format; they just store the number of ticks since a baseline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the editor is rendering [an HTML date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), the `value` attribute needs to use the `yyyy-MM-dd` format for the browser to recognise it as a valid date. The browser will then take care of displaying the value to the user in the format they expect, depending on their language settings.

You could modify the `EditorFor` calls to specify the date format:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @value = Model.Hire_Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), @class = "datepicker" } })
```

Or you could specify the format string on the model, and remove the `value` attribute from the `EditorFor` call:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime Hire_Date { get; set; }
```

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
```

Or you could add a custom editor template in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Date.cshtml':

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
    htmlAttrributes["type"] = "date";
}

@Html.TextBox("", Model?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), htmlAttributes)
```

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime Hire_Date { get; set; }
```

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond, the first answer was the best. Although, could you edit the answer to ````@Value```` instead of ````value````? That is what worked for me, ````value```` did not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set values as per following when you set property with [DataType(DataType.Date)]

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = @Model.Hire_Date.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy"), @class = "datepicker" } })`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated my question to reflect what I have changed, but this has not changed anything. What could I try next or why might this not be working?

Comment: Can you please share your controller code as well?

Comment: I edited my question again and provided the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your View: 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { @type="date", @class = "form-control datepicker",@id ="Hire_Date"} )

In your Model:
[Display(Name = "Hire_Date")]
[BindProperty, DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Hire_Date is required...")]
[MaxLength(10)]
[StringLength(10)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[RegularExpression(@"/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/")]
public DateTime DataResgate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?